# jquery master page problem

Tags: asp.net, jquery

i am developing an asp.net project and i use jquery with it but when I use masterpage with content page. My jquery code does not working but if ı use in a normal page without master jquery work efficiently.

`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/js/Default.js") %>' ></ script>`

I use this in the master page for resolation.

In my code when click a button. a timer starts and button disabled until timer finishes Thats all but not working with master page

Comment: Maybe the url you provide is not correct? You should take a look at the source code of the issue page to check if the src of js file is correct.

Comment: do alert(jQuery) if its giving undefined than definetely jQuery is not included properly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should try using ResolveUrl instead of ResolveClientUrl.

When using ResolveClientUrl the path is resolved relative to the location of the master page instead of the current page. ResolveUrl will resolve relative to the application root.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is below.  I ran into this issue a while ago.  To fix it I changed the src tag so that it uses databinding ("#") instead of resposne write ("=").  So in your code behind you have to call Page.Header.DataBind to resolve it.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src='<%# ResolveClientUrl("~/JScript.js") %>' ></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

Code Behind:

```
Partial Class MasterPage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Page.Header.DataBind()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: @boraer When the page loads in your browser and you do a view source:
-Do you see the <script....></script> block at all?
-Is the path being displayed correct?

--Thanks